# Html SELECT : send both value and text on submit

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `select`

```
<select name="country" multiple>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

While submitting form If both country is selected, default behaviour is, it will be send as:

```
country=IN,country=US
```

but i want to send both value and text i.e `IN` and `INDIA` both. How it can be done

Comment: Create a hidded field and update that value via JS

Comment: Change the value to the country name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give this a try:

```
$("#btnSub").on('click',function(){ // Submit button click
  $(".select option:selected").each(function(i, option){
    console.log($(this).val() + "," + $(this).text());
  });
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="select" name="country" multiple="multiple"> </select>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jc7KV/)

Comment: Fiddle works completely fine select multiple country then click on submit and check browser console!

Answer (score 3):

Posting the form will only send the "value" of the option to your backend, so if you also need the text, you could combine them in value like

```
<option value="IN,India">India<option>
```

and then split the value by the separator in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your request data yourself with jquery. Something like : (Not tested, might need a few corrections but here's the idea)

```
//POST request
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var countryVal = $("[name=country]").val();
    var countryLbl = $("[name=country]").find("option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
         data:{countryVal:countryVal, countryLbl: countryLbl},
         url: yourUrl,
         method:'post'
    });
    return false;
});

// GET request
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var countryVal = $("[name=country]").val();
    var countryLbl = $("[name=country]").find("option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
         url: 'yourUrl?countryVal='+countryVal+'&countryLbl='+countryLbl'
    });
    return false;
});
```

This work if you're ok with ajax request. If you're not, set hidden input in your form and set the value before submit :

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    $("[name=countryVal"]).val($("[name=country]").val());
    $("[name=countryLbl]").val($("[name=country]").find("option:selected").text());
});
```

Comment: You are not considering multiple selection

Comment: It would work the same. A few modifications and you're good to go. `$.each`